# Kapt gradle task Exception : class cast exception

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptSomethingDebugKotlin'.

i have refactored some of my class and i have added some kotlin classes and classes with bare functions.

when i try to compile the project , these weird things happen and none of the exception stack trace help me.

it seems this problem is due to Kotlin java combination

```
Unable to receive command from client socket connection from /127.0.0.1:5573 to /127.0.0.1:13020. Discarding connection.

org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:13020'.
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnectin.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection.receive(SynchronizedDispatchConnection.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection$1.run(DefaultDaemonConnection.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:79)
        ... 8 more

Unable to receive command from client socket connection from /127.0.0.1:5573 to /127.0
.0.1:13025. Discarding connection.org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:13025'.
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection.receive(SynchronizedDispatchConnection.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection$1.run(DefaultDaemonConnection.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:79)
        ... 8 more

Unable to receive command from client socket connection from /127.0.0.1:5573 to /127.0.0.1:13033. Discarding connection.
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:13033'.
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection.receive(SynchronizedDispatchConnection.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection$1.run(DefaultDaemonConnection.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:79)
        ... 8 more
Unable to receive command from client socket connection from /127.0.0.1:5573 to /127.0.0.1:13040. Discarding connection.
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:13040'.
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection.receive(SynchronizedDispatchConnection.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection$1.run(DefaultDaemonConnection.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:79)
        ... 8 more



e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.ClassCastException
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Comment: Please try to kill GradleDaemon and KotlinCompileDaemon processes, and start the build again.

Answer (score 0):

after a week of trial and failure and commenting and uncommenting line by line , i realized that it was a bug in kotlin to java compiler and every time i wrote a kotlin function which had no curly braces this exception was thrown

the reason was that i had not specified function return type and my function had only one statement which was appended as the body of function whit an equal sign.this way we depend on kotlin to identify the retuen type of function by the return type of that only statement.

when you put that one line statement in curly braces and specify the return type explicitly , the exception goes away